# Wordpress Customizer With External CSS File

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is It possible Wordpress Customizer to create Dynamic CSS file and use it as external css file instead of Inlining it in header with function

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_css');
```

I need to make Header More Clean as it contains lots of CSS in header right now..

Answer (score 0):

Some solution is to create PHP file which returns CSS code based on the variables provided via the GET parameters.

BUT:

1) You have to prepare a very strict sanitization as inproper value filtering can lead to security vulnerabilities,

2) The list of params cannot be too long as servers can have limits for the maximum URL length.